# Preimage of unit in algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebras

If $A,B$ are unital algebras, then for any homomorphism $\psi:A\rightarrow B$ we have $\psi(1_A)=1_B$. What can we say about structure of algebras $A,B$ if the preimage of $\{1_B\}$ is equal $\{1_A\}$ for any $\psi\in \mathrm{Hom}(A,B)$?

Comment: No, I don't have such an example. This question arise in discussion, when I came from the university. I tried find some non-trivial examples, but without success.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Correcting my deleted comment, if $B = \{0,1\}$ and, for concreteness, let's say $A$ is the free (unital, associative) algebra generated from a set $S$, then define $f$ by $f(s) = 0$ for $s \in S$.

Comment: So is there any example with "non-trivial" $A$ or $B$ ?